# How to create custom keyboard in telegram bot with python?

Tags: python, telegram

my code is:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler , MessageHandler, Filters

token = Updater("token")
reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.KeyboardButton('Share contact', request_contact=True)]])
```

and there is an error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myFirstBot.py", line 15, in 
    reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.KeyboardButton('Share contact', request_contact=True)]])
NameError: name 'telegram' is not defined

Comment: In your `reply_markup = ...` line, the variable `telegram` is not defined. Maybe you forgot to add `import telegram`?

Comment: telegram package is installed and and as you see in 1st line I imported Updater from ext in Telegram

Comment: I know, but you never import telegram itself, which is required to use it. I suggest you add `import telegram`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports in Python don't work that way. You should add `telegram` import as well. You only imported 4 classes into you code but not `telegram` nor `telegram.ext` module itself.

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

token = Updater("token")
reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.KeyboardButton('Share contact', request_contact=True)]])
```